# Htaccess redirect and rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get below URL to do a redirect / rewrite

```
http://www.domain.com.au/posting?id=44404
```

Below is what is required:

```
http://www.domain.com.au/state/category/job_title
```

Is there a way to do this with PHP MySQL Joomla application?

This is using custom component so I have to retrieve state, category and job_title information from MySQL database. Is there a way to insert them into htaccess or recognise so that it reflects on the URL field instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can write a script to get from `/state/category/job_title` to an id, then you can use a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap). You can only define a map in either the server config or a vhost config, not in an `.htaccess` file.

Say you had a perl script that parsed out the state, category, and job_title, did some database lookups, then output `44404` or whatever the id is. Then you can define the mapping like so:

```
RewriteMap jobmap prg:/path/to/your/script.pl
```

Then in the `htaccess` file in your document root, you can use the map:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /posting?id=${jobmap:$1/$2/$3}
```

If you wanted to enumerate every `state/category/job_title` combination, you could also use a [text file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#txt) or a [dbm file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbm). Or if you have mod_dbd loaded and configured, you can also use a [SQL select query](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbd)

Another alternative is to write some kind of php script and route everything through that. It would essentially be doing what the `script.pl` example would do, parse out the `state/category/job_title` fields, and do the proper database lookup to obtain an id. You could then include the posting script and hand over the id.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html

but, as you redirect, your id gets lost

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write all the codes to replace each id with the needed category state and job title in the .htaccess file, I dont think you can retrieve through mysql and use them to replace in the htaccess file.